# Store selector as value in an NSDictionary

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary, selector

Is there a way to store a selector in an `NSDictionary`, without storing it as an `NSString`?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

`SEL` is just a pointer, which you could store in an `NSValue`:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                       [NSValue valueWithPointer:@selector(foo)], @"foo",
                       nil];
```

To get the selector back, you can use:

```
SEL aSel = [[dict objectForKey:@"foo"] pointerValue];
```

Comment: Maybe also mention that to get the SEL back, you have to do: `SEL *aSel = [[dict objectForKey:@"foo"] pointerValue];`

Comment: When I retrieve SEL as you suggest and try self performSelector:*aSel withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0]; I get: EXC_BAD_ACCESS. The correct way of retrieving them is SEL aSel = [[dict objectForKey:@"foo"] pointerValue];
[self performSelector:aSel withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];

Comment: Newbie question: How do you execute your selector?

Comment: @JohanKarlsson: E.g. using one of the `performSelector:` variants. More detail would be better suited for a new question though.

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche IMHO your answer would be more complete if you just add one row as an example on how to use the SEL. Not so much work, but nice. Only a suggestion.

I agree that how to use selector in a more wide approach could be a question own its own.

Comment: Ah, this is why I'm still in love with Objective-C - it's super dynamic and total freedom for the mind! :)

Answer (score 10):

An alternative to Georg's solution would be to convert the selector into an NSString before storing it the NSDictionary:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                      NSStringFromSelector(@selector(foo)), @"foo",
                      nil];

SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString([dict objectForKey:@"foo"]);
```

This technique, though uses more memory, gives you the ability to serialize the entire NSDictionary as a string via libraries like JSONKit.

Comment: Georg, it was my fault. I did set a selector for the dictionary key used to retrieve it. Thanks for following up. I'll update my answer.

Comment: *Oops, typo. I meant to say: "I forgot to set a selector value for that key in the dictionary."

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Good to hear you figured it out.

Comment: If you're using strings for the selector names I would recommend using `[obj respondsToSelector:selector]` to guard against typos.

Answer (score 6):

An `NSDictionary` is really just a `CFDictionary` that retains and releases all keys and values.  If you create a `CFDictionary` directly, you can set it up to not retain and release  values.  You can typecast a `CFDictionaryRef` to an `NSDictionary *` and vice versa.

Comment: I do this quite a bit for when I have Foundation objects as keys but non-Foundation objects as values.

Answer (score 3):

In case of using `UILocalNotification` the only way is to use `NSSelectorFromString([dict objectForKey:@"foo"])`. With `valueWithPointer` the app crashing when setting userInfo property of `UILocalNotification` object. Be careful.

Answer (score 2):

While [Georg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822602/store-selector-as-value-in-an-nsdictionary#answer-2822631) should work, `NSValue` does also support encoding any value using an Objective-C type encoding string, which has a special way of representing `SEL`— with a `":"` *(as opposed to the `"^v"` produced by `-valueWithPointer:`, which translates into `void *`)*.
*<sub>source: [Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide - Type Encodings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html)</sub>*

Working off of Georg's solution, the best API-compliant way to put a `SEL` into an `NSValue` into an `NSDictionary` would be:

```
// store
NSDictionary *dict = @{
    @"foo": [NSValue value:&@selector(foo) withObjCType:@encode(SEL)]
};

// retrieve
SEL aSel;
[dict[@"foo"] getValue:&aSel];
```

---

The rationale for handling a `SEL` as its own beast is that the docs describe it as “an opaque type”— which means that its internal workings (even what it's `typedef`d to) are off-limits to app programmers; Apple may mix it up at any time in the future.

Also, using `void *`s to force the system to do what you want it to do was useful in C back in the '90s, when most of us didn't know any better.  *You're better than that now.*

The above approach should only be used if the retrieval of the `SEL` happens during the program's running duration— you shouldn't be storing that `NSDictionary` to disk.  If you do need to store `SEL`s long-term (across app launches), you should follow [David H's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822602/store-selector-as-value-in-an-nsdictionary#answer-9258991) and convert it to an `NSString`.